# HTML Submit on a whole <tr>

Tags: html, form-submit, forms

I'm currently doing a webpage that diplays a table containing all of the online orders a customer have made.
What I want to do is that each line would be clickable and would lead to another page containing the details of the clicked order.

I am trying to do it this way :

```
<form action="/Pailley/index.php?page=402" target="_blank" method="POST">
    <input name="id_commande" type="number" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" hidden>
    <tr class="champ_tableau">
        <td>xx/xx/xxxx</td>
        <td>xxxxxxxxxxxx</td>
        <td>xxx,xx €</td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

Here's the thing, how to I make the entire line the Submit button ?
Also it doesn't look clean at all but it's the only way I see to do it, in PHP at least. If you have any suggestion on making cleaner I'd be glad to hear it :)

[How I want to be able to click it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfFJD.png)

Comment: Would each line take you to the *same* place, or to *different* places? Also note that your markup is invalid; `<tr>` elements must come inside a `<table>` element (`<thead>`, `<tbody>` and `<tfoot>` inclusive); not a `<form>` element.

Comment: Make each `<td>` inside there clickable. The `<tr>` might not actually have a non-zero height.

Comment: Different places, each line is a different order ^^

Comment: This sounds like a job for Javascript.